# Can we use 2 Func's with same name? Compiler doesn't throw any error

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

In the below code i have created 2 Funcs 1)Class level and 2) inside a method with same name and all same. When i build the solution it doesn't throw any errors and it is executing completely fine. 
now i am interested to invoke the Func of class member but i don't find how to do it. Can some one help me on it.

```
public class TaskDemo
{
    public int NumberStrat { get; set; }
    public int NumberEnd { get; set; }

    Func<int, string> isNumerEvenOdd = (i) =>
    {
        return i.ToString();
    };

    public void print()
    {

        List<int> NumbersList = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            NumbersList.Add(i);
        }

        Func<int, string> isNumerEvenOdd = (i) =>
        {
            return "abc";
        };

        Parallel.ForEach(NumbersList, (i) => Console.WriteLine(isNumerEvenOdd(i)));

    }
}
```

Comment: You are getting the warning that local variable hides class field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **this** keyword.

```
Parallel.ForEach(NumbersList, (i) => Console.WriteLine(this.isNumerEvenOdd(i)));
```

example -> https://onlinegdb.com/SkRpXyCRH

for more information -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this

Comment: Thanks for the response, But using of "this" doesn't seems to solve the issue and also i am curious to know why the compiler doesn't throw any error.

Comment: It should call the class member `isNumerEvenOdd` instead of the local variable, if you prefix it with `this.`. At least it does when I test it.

Comment: And the reason why it doesn't give you an error is because this is completely legal. A local variable is closer to the scope of the code and thus have priority. It is allowed to have duplicate identifiers across different scopes, just not in the same scope. So this is fine.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I've just explained it in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a warning (at least, in Resharper) that your local declaration of `Func<int, string> isNumerEvenOdd` hides the `Func<int, string> isNumerEvenOdd` declared at the class level and it's never used. So, the local member just hiding the class member and works fine.

The reason why there is no compiler error because you defined the variables with the same name in a different scopes (class and method). Compiler shows an error when you try to define the variables with the same name in the same scope

Actually using `this` will solve you issue here `Parallel.ForEach(NumbersList, (i) => Console.WriteLine(this.isNumerEvenOdd(i)));`, as previous answer says, because in this case you are referring to field defined at class scope, rather than in method scope.

> The `this` keyword refers to the current instance of the class